# the colored block in debug trace won't move forward?

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm new here and this is my first question on stackoverflow.

When I debug php source in eclipse, the colored debugging block does not move, even if I press F5 or F6.

In fact, the debugging trace goes forward surely, and the values of the variables show the correct values. But the colored block will not move.

I googled many times about this but I can't find any solution on the internet or on stackoverflow.

Does anybody have the same error?
Can anyone help me?

My environment is as follows : 
windows7 64bit
XAMPP(APACHE, mysql, php)
Eclipse : Eclipse Java EE  4.4.1 
(even Luna 4.41 Eclipse for php version has the same error)

php Ver : 5.5.15
mysql  Ver : 14.14 Distrib 5.6.20, for Win32 (x86)
Apache Verk : Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) 
PDT(PHP Debugging Tool), xDebug is installed

Comment: I found the reason : elclipse bug in luna version. So I use kepler eclipse now.

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse from Help> Install New Software add below REPO
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.3.2/
update all PDT

Comment: Thanks a lot Nader Sediq ^^